# Linq to SQL Compact - Transaction or just SubmitChanges

Tags: linq-to-sql, transactions, sql-server-ce

I'm using Linq to SQL on an SQL Compact database. I have a function where I insert multiple records into the database. I only call SubmitChanges at the end of the function. Would using a transaction (using the TransactionScope class) bring me any more performance or advantages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Linq to SQL uses a transaction within SubmitChanges, so you should not need to use one explicitly. [From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399378.aspx):

*Immediately before any actual changes are transmitted, LINQ to SQL starts a transaction to encapsulate the series of individual commands.*